# Collection of sub line bundles of a vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

Let X/k be a projective integral variety over a field, with fixed $\mathcal{O}(1)$, $\mathcal{E}$ be a rank two vector bundle, for simplicity assume it is stable. Regarding the collection of sub line bundles $\mathcal{L}\subset \mathcal{E}$ up to isomorphism,

*EDIT:* and moreover $\mathcal{L}$ is the line bundle given by an effective divisor,

denoted this collection by $Sub(\mathcal{E})$, I have the following questions:

(1) When is this collection finite?

(2) Take another scheme $T/k$, and base change $X_T/T$, when is $Sub(\mathcal{E}_T)=Sub(\mathcal{E})_T$ ?

(3) If the above equality doesn't hold, when does $Sub(\mathcal{E}_T)=Sub(\mathcal{E})_T$ up to tensoring pull back of a line bundle on T?

(4) If the answer to (2) and (3) are not very trivial, then consider the functor $Sub(\mathcal{E}_T\otimes f_T^*(\mathcal{N}))$, where $f:X\rightarrow \mathcal{S}pec\ k$ is the structure morphism,  $\mathcal{N}$ is a line bundle on T, and we identify two sub line bundles of $\mathcal{E}$ up to tensoring with $f^*_T(\mathcal{N})$. When is this functor representable?

*Edit*: Here by a sub line bundle I just mean a rank one subsheaf which is itself a line bundle; i.e. in an exact sequence like $0\rightarrow \mathcal{L}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{Q}\rightarrow 0$, I didn't mean both $\mathcal{L}$ and the "quotient" $\mathcal{Q}$ are line bundles.

Comment: Consider a vector bundle on $\mathbb P^1$, say the rank-2 trivial bundle. I argue that it contains sub-line bundles of arbitrarily low degree.

The section $(x^n,1)$ has a degree $n$ pole at $\infty$ but no zeroes. Furthermore it generates a line bundle, which will have degree $-n$.

For this reason, I suspect the collection is rarely finite.

What is an effective line bundle? Is it a line bundle given by an effective divisor? On $\mathbb P^1$, at least, those are finite, because there is a maximum degree. Similar results should hold over, at least, every curve.

Comment: It is certainly true that for any curve the collection is always infinite; on the other hand, it is easy to give examples in higher dimension where it is empty. I doubt that there is a general criterion. As a general comment, questions of the type "When does this happen" are rather hard to answer. The OP should really make an effort to explain what he has in mind

Comment: If one has the property that $H^1(X,L)=0$ for every line bundle $L$ on $X$, then this is equivalent to saying $Ext^1(L_1,L_2)=0$ for any line bundles $L_1,L_2$.  In this setting, if a rank $2$ vector bundle $E$ admits a line subbundle $L$, then the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow E \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0$ must split, so $E$ has only $2$ possible line subbundles.

Comment: As for the motivation, the idea is this: generically a zero locus of a section in $\mathcal{E}$ will cut out a codimension two subscheme of X, given $\mathcal{E}$ is a rank two vector bundle, and generically it is even smooth. But when the section comes from a sub line bundle, it will cut out a divisor. So I want to rule them out.(to be continued...)

Comment: (continued) And yes by an effective line bundle I meant a line bundle given by an effective divisor, by equivalently $H^0(X, \mathcal{L})\neq 0$. Now if I give $H^0(X,\mathcal{E})/k^*$ the natural projective space structure, where we assume $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)=k$, and when I rule out those (hopefully finite) closed subset $H^0(X,\mathcal{L})/k^*$, then I get an open set $U$. My core interest is whether this open set $U$ represents any reasonable functor. However, when the collection of "effective" sub line bundles is not finite, this $U$ is only constructible and less desirable. 

Comment: @Sawin: Thanks for your example. As for the finiteness for "effective"  line bundles, I think it is true when $Pic^0(X)=0$ i.e. $Pic(X)$ is discrete (and we know it has finite rank), then by similar arguments of "maximal degree" one can show it is finite. But I don't know how to do it in general. Actually, the situation that interests me most is when X is a threefold, $\mathcal{E}$ is rank two vector bundle. 


Comment: @Parsa: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think the term "sub line bundles" might be confusing, so I have edited my question. Here in exact sequence like $0\rightarrow \mathcal{L}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{Q}\rightarrow 0$, I didn't require both $\mathcal{L}$ and the "quotient" $\mathcal{Q}$ are line bundles. In my terminology, I just require $\mathcal{L}$ to be a rank one subsheaf which is locally free. Sorry about not clarifying my terminology in the beginning!